# Unable to remove local file after upload in Chrome

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-chrome, file-upload, dropzone.js

I am developing an application using CodeIgniter and am using a dropzone.js fileuploader to allow users to upload images. Most of the time the local source for these images will be in a temporary images folder on a network share. I want to remove the local file (if it is in the temp folder) after the upload is complete. I can get it to work just fine in Firefox and the Chrome extension Postman, but not in the Chrome browser itself.

After handling the upload i call:

```
$file = 'smb://Server/share/' . $_FILES['file']['name'];
if (file_exists($file))
{
    unlink($file);
}
```

In the Chrome console I get the following error:

```
<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>
<p>Severity: Warning</p>
<p>Message:  unlink(): Unlink fails: Device or resource busy</p>
<p>Filename: models/Model_user_images.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 204</p>
```

Since it works in Firefox I am assuming that it is not a server problem. The only thing I can think of is that Chrome somehow locks the uploaded file, but I can't think of anything to prevent this.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your directory has permission to delete files (Permission: 777)

Comment: Like I said, it works if I use Firefox, so it is not a directory permission issue